# can't connect to wifi ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

Is there a way to connect to wifi?

Nothing works with Ubuntu in respect to wifi.

I used to click on the wifi icon and select connect to a hidden wifi network and then create a new NETWORK so I can edit the password field but even this doesn't seem to work!

Of'course the other alternatives like:

- Create new wifi network or,
- Edit connections

BUT they do NOT work either!!!

Still it feels like 1999 in Linux field....

Comment: when you boot up using a LiveUSB memory stick with the ubuntu ISO burned onto it you should be able to login to wifi ... this validates your hardware as wifi ready ...  if true then the install is somehow mucked up

Comment: Please [edit] with https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1004020

Comment: i'll make a bookmark for this script!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Ubuntu community refuses to solve genuinely and professionaly this long-standing problem and explains why Windows remains - and it will - #1 OS in the market!

The workaround:

1. from network icon open the drop-down menu and select "Connect to Hidden WiFi Network"
2. On the window enter:

[image]

a) Leave it to "New.."

b) At field "Network name" enter EXACTLY the name of the failed-to-login network

c) At "WiFi Security" drop-down list select "WPA & WPA2 Personal"

d) at the "Password" input field enter router's password.

From that point on you'll be ready to connect on the not-so-hidden wifi network!

Good luck!

PS: I'll be happy to switch to another flavor of linux if it solves natively this problem!
My system is Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, now it works and detects all wifi networks. Indeed, it is a shame that in the year of our lord 2024 we still have to deal with this bullshit. It's not 2009 anymore, Canonical, fix this, please. 

It was funny though, that your interface does look like from 2009, so I was very confused thinking I was looking at a very old post.

Comment: Yes I load a minimal graphical interface!

Comment: What "network icon"?